# app file disabled and not uploaded after Shared my android project to Github

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

i decided to share my android project to **Github**  from android studio By  doing this way

> VCS > Import into Version Control > Share Project On Github

i found that project uploaded Successfully but the app folder doesn't uploaded and it show this [ICON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHBas.png)

it kind disabled but after i Cloned the project i found the app folder didn't uploaded from the beginning  i tried to push the project from

```
 Visual Studio code
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you added app folder with Git?

check the status of your app directory with

```
git status
```

if your directory not added with git yet. please add your app directory by

```
git add "directory name"
```

if want to add all file of the directory so use

```
git add "directory name"/*
```

"*" will add all file of that directory

Then Commit and Push Again Your Project.

Comment: i did what u say but still not committed it said  Failed to push directory

Comment: Is it Merge Issue occur when trying to push again?

Comment: Can you share whole error here, which occur when trying to push your project?